# Upload CSVs of JSON data from S3 To Redshift

Tags: json, csv, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, amazon-redshift

I have thousands of unusually formatted CSVs sitting in S3 that I need uploaded to Redshift.

The CSVs are formatted like so:

```
 Column A            Column B            ..... Column Z
{"id": 2034823"   "created": "2017-1-1"       "result": true}
```

In other words, each row of the CSV is valid JSON.

I've tried a simple copy command, but to no avail. I tried to add the `format as json 'auto';` flag, but still receiving errors:

`Invalid Value: err_code 1216, line number 1, position 0`

Is there a recommended way to handle CSVs in this format? I want to save them into an existing Redshift table that already has types defined

Comment: Are you trying to store the values as strings? Because if you're trying to store them as json objects you will need to use Redshift Spectrum

Comment: Updating: I want to save them into an existing Redshift table that already has types defined

Comment: This COPY should work with `FORMAT AS JSON 'auto'`. It's probably a type mismatch issue. Can you add more info from `stl_load_errors`?

Comment: it says `position 0`, raw_line `.....]..data_1.json`, err_code `1216`, err_reason `Invalid value`

Answer (score 1):

I have the same exact types of files. The steps I have followed to load them into a Redshift table like this

1. Create an external table in Redshift Spectrum table with `struct`
2. Insert into your Redshift table from the table above.

in your case

```
1. 
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE <spectrum schema>.<your external table>
(
data struct<
id:integer,
created:timestamp,
...
result:varchar(5)>
)
row format serde 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe'
with serdeproperties (
'dots.in.keys' = 'true',
'mapping.requesttime' = 'requesttimestamp')
 as location 's3:<your S3 bucket>';

2.
INSERT INTO <your Redshift table> 
SELECT data.id, data.created, ..., data.result
  FROM <your external table>
```

See how to setup Redshift Spectrum
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c-getting-started-using-spectrum.html

Let me know if you have further questions.